# Firewall blocking screen sharing with 20.04 desktop ubuntu installation

Tags: networking, ssh, xorg, sharing, firewire

Can any of you knowledgeable persons, tell me how to enable screen sharing with ubuntu desktop 20.04 vnc X11VNC server. I was initially able to connect to the server ubuntu desktop on first attempt, but when I subsequently tried I have been given the message, when trying to connect from my MAC  using the client "Remote Desktop -VNC" that the machine is either unavailable  or firewall is blocking screen sharing.

Answer (score 1):

To test if its a firewall problem try:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

This will disable the whole firewall. Now you should be able to connect. If this worked then just reenable the firewall with

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Then just add a firewall rule with:

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 5900 proto tcp
```

Worked for me. Source: https://linuxconfig.org/remote-desktop-sharing-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa